# is there an expression ideal for prettifying this javascript conditional?

Tags: javascript

Is there an operator (in lodash etc) that can clean up this conditional expression?

```
if (foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.baz  !== '') {
   ....
}
```

Comment: `foo?.bar?.baz !== ''`?

Comment: native javascript: [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) as follows:

```
if (foo?.bar?.baz !== '') {
   ....
}
```

Comment: While this is clearly the right answer, it's worth mentioning this is a relatively new feature so it might not be 100% to use without a linter/transpiler

Comment: No, as written, this doesn't give the same logic    https://jsfiddle.net/L31qfmtu/41/

Comment: @dataman: You probably want `if ((foo?.bar?.baz ?? '') !== '')`.

Comment: @FelixKling unfortunately that breaks for the case of: const foo = { bar: {baz2: "33"}};

Comment: @dataman: In that case I guess you can only partially reduce the expression to `if (foo?.bar && foo.bar.baz !== '')`.